# sp con servidor vinculado funciona en Management sql server pero no desde java

Tags: java, sql-server, servidor, transacciones

tengo 2 servidores de base de datos vinculados entre si, con bases replicadas.

Un trabajo continuo que tengo es migrar datos de una tabla a su respectiva del otro servidor, para esto cree unos SP en uno de los servidores que se encarga de la actualización y corre correctamente desde un management o un dbeaber directamente en el motor.

Pero cuando lo quiero correr desde un java aplication común mi llamada al sp devuelve el siguiente error:

> No se pudo realizar la operación porque el proveedor OLE DB "SQLNCLI"
>   para el servidor vinculado [SERVIDOR-2] no pudo iniciar una
>   transacción distribuida.

Desde ya agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar, 
Saludos.

Comment: Tenes habilitada la opción de RPC ó RPC Out en tu servidor vinculado?

Comment: no estoy seguro, lo revisare en todo caso que provocaria no tener habilidata alguna de estas opciones?

Comment: RPC es "remote call procedure", básicamente es una opción de seguridad que evita que terceros no autorizados ejecuten los SP